# SnipMate with Pathogen

Tags: vim, snipmate, pathogen

I've just installed [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) on my `~/.vim` and add the new command to run the bundles

```
:call pathogen#infect()
```

I've already add to my `~/.vim/bundle` folder vim-surround and NERDtree and everything works great. Nevertheless, when I tried to add [garbas](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) SnipMate it didn't work. Could someone help with this issue? Thanks

Comment: I see that this new version of SnipMate has a few dependencies (the original didn't), did you install them as well? Also do you have some error messages?

Comment: I did exactly the pathogen installation written in garbas link, I also tried the original snipmate version from [msanders](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) adding the snipmate.vim into ~/.vim/bundle and it didn't work too. It doesn't appears any error message, even when I try to run vim -V test.c

Comment: You say "adding the snipmate.vim into ~/.vim/bundle". Do you talk about a "snipmate.vim" file or the whole folder with its 7 subfolders?

Comment: I did cd ~/.vim/bundle and then git clone git://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't now why but when I remove the option

```
set paste
```

from my .vimrc the snipmate pluging start work perfectly.

Comment: This was the problem for me as well I had set paste in my .vimrc when I commented out "set paste then snipmate worked fine.

Answer (score 16):

I installed snimpmate following this guide with no problem at all [John Andersons vim guide](http://sontek.net/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide)

```
$ mkdir ~/.vim/
$ mkdir ~/.vim/{autoload,bundle}
$ cd ~/.vim/
$ git init

git submodule add https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim.git bundle/snipmate
```

To create your own snippets

```
$ mkdir ~/.vim/snippets
$ vim ~/.vim/snippets/python.snippets
```

His example for pdb snippet

```
snippet pdb
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

You should be then good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The official way of snipmate distribution is [vim-addon-manager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905). Like pathogen it puts each plugin in a separate folder, but it also does more, see the documentation. I have not tried pathogen at all, but I know what may be the cause here:

1. You forgot to install some dependencies. In this case it is likely that some errors will be thrown.
2. Pathogen is not sourcing `after/` directory (and vim won't do this for all &runtimepath items, just for a few as documented in `:h after-directory`). As far as I know all mappings are located there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not obvious, but `snippets/` directory must be at `.vim/`.

```
$ mkdir ~/.vim/snippets
$ vim ~/.vim/snippets/python.snippets
```

At least one snippet:

```
snippet pdb
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```